# Returning multiples of a number in Python

Tags: python, integer, range

How can I get the multiples of a number in a certain range.

```
For example:

For 10 in range(100):
returns => [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

For 9 in range(100):
returns => [9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99]

For 7 in range(100):
returns => [7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98]
```

Comment: Have you bothered to read the [documentation of range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the proper `start, stop and step` arguments to the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function.

```
>>> print(list(range(0, 100, 10)))
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

>>> print(list(range(0, 100, 9)))
[0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99]

>>> print(list(range(0, 100, 7)))
[0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98]
```

Answer (score 0):

range(min (inclusive), max (exclusive), multiple)

Example:

```
>>> range(0, 10, 2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Multiples of 2 that are >= 0 and < 10.